# Как увеличить шрифт по всему сайт по клику на кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.item.level-1 {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.item.level-2 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.item.level-3 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
SCHRIFT

<div class="wrap">
  <button class="item level-1">A</button>
  <button class="item level-2">A</button>
  <button class="item level-3">A</button>
</div>

<h3>level 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>

<h3>level 3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.wrap').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
     document.body.style.fontSize = `${e.target.dataset.font}rem`;  
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button data-font='0.7' class="level-1">Small</button>
  <button data-font='1' class="level-2">Normal</button>
  <button data-font='1.3' class="level-3">Large</button>
</div>

<h3>level 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>

<h3>level 3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>
```

Comment: Вот это чудеса, сразу видно мастера =)

Comment: спасибо, а html стоит задать font-size в пикселях?

Answer (score 0):

Меняет шрифт только тексту, который лежит в теге **< p >**

```js
let level_1 = document.querySelector('.item.level-1');
let level_2 = document.querySelector('.item.level-2');
let level_3 = document.querySelector('.item.level-3');
let texts   = document.querySelectorAll('p');

level_1.onclick = function(){
for(let elem of texts){ 
elem.style.fontSize = "11px";   
}       
}

level_2.onclick = function (){
for(let elem of texts){ 
elem.style.fontSize = "14px";   
}       
}

level_3.onclick = function (){
for(let elem of texts){ 
elem.style.fontSize = "16px";   
}       
}
```

```css
.item.level-1 {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.item.level-2 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.item.level-3 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="item level-1">A</button>
  <button class="item level-2">A</button>
  <button class="item level-3">A</button>
</div>
<div class ="texts">
<h3>level 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>

<h3>level 3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumq
```

Если нужно, чтобы весь текст на сайте менял свой шрифт.

```js
let level_1 = document.querySelector('.item.level-1');
let level_2 = document.querySelector('.item.level-2');
let level_3 = document.querySelector('.item.level-3');
let texts   = document.querySelector('.main');
let heading = document.querySelectorAll('h3');

level_1.onclick = function(){
for(let elem of heading){
elem.style.fontSize = '11px';   
}
texts.style.fontSize = '11px';
}

level_2.onclick = function(){
for(let elem of heading){
elem.style.fontSize = '14px';   
}
texts.style.fontSize = '14px';
}

level_3.onclick = function(){
for(let elem of heading){
elem.style.fontSize = '16px';   
}
texts.style.fontSize = '16px';
}
```

```css
body{
font-size:16px;     
}

.item.level-1 {
font-size: 11px;
}

.item.level-2 {
font-size: 14px;
}

.item.level-3 {
font-size: 16px;
}

h3 {
font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="item level-1">A</button>
  <button class="item level-2">A</button>
  <button class="item level-3">A</button>
</div>

<h3>level 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>

<h3>level 3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но нюанс в том, что нужно на всем сайте такое сделать. Есть вариант, где понадобиться меньше кода? или нет?

Comment: К сожалению, нет =(
Коротких кодов на чистом js не бывает.

Comment: Количество текста на сайте не влияет на размер данного JS кода =) 
Чтобы код работал правильно,  в html разметке нужно весь текст, который мы хотим увеличить заключить в тег <p></p>

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю то ли вы имели ввиду, но как я понял, то как-то так

```js
let btns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
let content = document.querySelector('.content');
btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click' , (e)=>{
    removeClasses();
    e.target.classList.contains('level-1') ? content.classList.add('level-1') : null;
    e.target.classList.contains('level-2') ? content.classList.add('level-2') : null;
    e.target.classList.contains('level-3') ? content.classList.add('level-3') : null;
    })
 
})

function removeClasses(){
  content.classList.remove('level-1' , 'level-2' , 'level-3');
}
```

```css
.content.level-1 , .content .level-1 {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.content.level-2 , .content .level-2{
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content.level-3 , .content .level-3 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
SCHRIFT
<div class = 'content'>

<div class="wrap">
  <button class="item level-1">A</button>
  <button class="item level-2">A</button>
  <button class="item level-3">A</button>
</div>

<h3>level 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>

<h3>level 3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но нюанс в том, что нужно на всем сайте такое сделать. Есть вариант, где понадобиться меньше кода? или нет?

Comment: этот код привязан к кнопкам, а не к количеству контента, так что размер контента не повлияет на величину текущего кода

Comment: чтоб было понятнее, как это работает:
вы нажимаете на кнопку, родительскому элементу в корне сайта добавляется класс, и в зависимости от этого класса применяется font-size всем дочерним элементам

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы легко и просто менять размер шрифтов сразу по всему сайту, нужно установить их не в абсолютных единицах (px), а в относительных. Например, в `rem` — т.е. относительно размера шрифта корневого элемента.

После этого достаточно менять размер лишь в одном месте:

```js
document.querySelector('.level-1').addEventListener( "click" , () => document.documentElement.style.fontSize  = '14px');
document.querySelector('.level-2').addEventListener( "click" , () => document.documentElement.style.fontSize  = '16px');
document.querySelector('.level-3').addEventListener( "click" , () => document.documentElement.style.fontSize  = '18px');
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.item.level-1 {
  font-size: 0.6885rem /* 11px */;
}

.item.level-2 {
  font-size: 0.875rem /* 14px */
}

.item.level-3 {
  font-size: 1rem /* 16px */
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem /* 20px */
}

p {
  font-size: 1.125rem /* 18px */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="item level-1">A</button>
  <button class="item level-2">A</button>
  <button class="item level-3">A</button>
</div>

<h3>level 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>

<h3>level 3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni unde iste officia molestiae. Ab veniam animi, quaerat, aperiam cumque labore vel nobis atque eveniet aliquid earum numquam ducimus et obcaecati.</p>
```

Comment: спасибо, но можно как -то обойтись без js в разметке?

Comment: @testcoder можно, конечно, вынести добавление "прослушки" кликов по кнопкам из разметки в блок js. Поправил.